# Impossible to connect to mongoDB Atlas: firewall issue? DNS issue? Have no idea

Tags: firewall

I'm following [this](https://fullstackopen.com/en/part3/saving_data_to_mongo_db#fetching-objects-from-the-database) fullstack course but I'm not able to connect to my mongoDB Atlas database.

To go directly to the issue, after trying many things to identify the root of the problem, I tried the (troubleshooting) Ensure network connectivity [here](https://docs.mlab.com/troubleshooting-atlas-connection-issues/#4-ensure-network-connectivity) with the cluster shard links and none of them worked. Particularly access it in the browser just kept "loading". When I ran the  `host my-atlas-cluster-shard-00-00-mdyjt.mongodb.net` (but with the good link) it returned not found. Would there be a way to fix this that would not require going to my "network administrator" or whatever that is?

Other things that I have tried/to know:

I have had a whitelist entry that allows access from anywhere as per the tutorial since the beginning and I'm certain my username is ok in the url (it is Database Acces one, etc.) so I don't think that's the issue.

I tried the code below (node, using mongoose) and it didn't work. And I suspected the issue isn't the code because it is copy pasted from the tutorial. I tried the official mongoDB node.js library and it also didn't work (also connection timeOut). I even installed MongoCompass and got a connection timeout (which is what confirms it isn't a coding error).

I did some research and it seems like the issue is my firewall blocks access to 27017, as suggested [here](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/troubleshoot-connection/#attempting-to-connect-to-a-cluster-from-behind-a-firewall), and I tried the http://portquiz.net:27017/ and at first it didn't work at all (the page never loaded). I temporarily disabled my ufw to try and now it sort of works: the page loads at the beginning, but it keeps "loading" (even if I can see the content) and after a while it disappears.

Then I temporarily allowed access for everything in iptables and the portquiz page worked (and didn't keep loading forever), but I still couldn't access my cluster. So I have no idea what's the issue here.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')


const url =  "/* here i put my url with the appropiate username, password, database name, etc.*/"

mongoose.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useFindAndModify: false, useCreateIndex: true })

const noteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({   content: String,   date: Date,   important: Boolean })

const Note = mongoose.model('Note', noteSchema)

const note = new Note({   content: 'HTML is Easy',   date: new Date(), important: true })

note.save().then(result => {   console.log('note saved!')   mongoose.connection.close() })
```

This is the error I get when I run that file:

```
/home/julia/test-rep/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:184
          callback(new MongooseError(message));
                   ^

MongooseError: Operation `notes.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/home/julia/test-rep/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:184:20)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:556:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:499:7)
```

I've gotten this error with MongoClient:

```
MongoServerSelectionError: connection timed out
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/julia/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:438:30)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:556:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:499:7)
```

as well as this error when going into more detail:

```
MongoServerSelectionError: connection timed out
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/julia/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:438:30)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:556:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:499:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    setName: 'atlas-z3fex8-shard-0',
    maxSetVersion: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    servers: Map(3) {
      '/*name of my*/cluster-shard-00-00.9a0bz.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      '/*name of my*/cluster-shard-00-02.9a0bz.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      '/*name of my*/cluster-shard-00-01.9a0bz.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    compatibilityError: null,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: 30,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    commonWireVersion: 8
  }
}
```

I think maybe there's some issue with my computer or who knows what.
I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: Does the first answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60063820/getting-replicasetnoprimary-and-mongoserverselectionerror-error-while-connecting is of any help? It might have something to do with whielisting your IP in the mongoDB settings.

Comment: @Vlad Sadly no, I already whitelisted my IP a while ago: it seems the issue is really with the port (http://portquiz.net:27017/ this link takes a lot of time to load).